# Karma test for primeng table

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine, primeng

I'm new to karma,and i want to run tests for primeng table.Need help on few scenarios.
 1.To verify headers
2.To verify checkbox in first column
 3.to verify number of rows/data repeated

```
<section>
      <p-table #dt [columns]="columns" [value]="data" id="accountsTable" formcontrolname="myTable">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
          <tr>
            <th class="actionColumn">
              &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [width]="col.width ? col.width : ''">
              {{col.header}}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>


      </p-table>
    </section>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Added the question